# How to get symbolic constant with glGet?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

Is it appropriate way to query OpenGL about symbolic constant value? Or there is more elegant way?

```
GLint sbf[20];
glGetIntegerv(GL_STENCIL_BACK_FAIL, sbf);
```

Note:

> GL_STENCIL_BACK_FAIL
>   data returns one value, a symbolic constant indicating what action is taken for back-facing polygons when the stencil test fails. The initial value is GL_KEEP. See glStencilOpSeparate.

Comment: Why do you declare such a large array for sbf?  Why not just say GLint sbf; then say glGetIntegerv(GL_STENCIL_BACK_FAIL, &sbf); ?

Comment: @jwlaughton I declare so large array to get all symbolic constant in it. Do you think that `GLint sbf` is an answer instead of `GLint sbf[20]`?

Comment: glGetIntegerv is only going to return a single value into sbf, so GLint sbf (maybe GLint sbf = 0; to initialize it) is appropriate.  There are, of course several possible values for this return, so you may want to implement some if statements to take whatever action you want depending on the return value.

Comment: I see in your note that you already understand this:  "GL_STENCIL_BACK_FAIL data returns one value", so maybe I misunderstand your question.

Comment: @jwlaughton It's true in this case that it will only return one value. But it depends on the enum passed as first argument. For some enum values, it will return multiple values.

Comment: @Rato Koradi True.  I think it can return up to 16 values if, for example, you ask for the projection matrix.  That's why I said maybe I misunderstood Yehor's question.

Comment: @Reto Koradi My bad, you would, of course, use glGetFloatv to get the projection matrix, but your point is still valid.  There are calls to glGetIntegerv that can return more than one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions are:

```
GLint sbf = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_STENCIL_BACK_FAIL, &sbf);
```

You can then take whatever actions you want by implementing if statements depending on the value of sbf.

Comment: Thank you @jwlaughton. Your approach is working correct for me.